# Sagemaker Local Mode: RuntimeError: Giving up, endpoint: didn't launch correctly

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

While running sagemaker in local mode.
I am experimenting with an inference endpoint in local mode using docker container. But as soon as my model.tar.gz file exceeds a certain size i.e. around 200 mb, the deployment fails and returns the error:
`RuntimeError: Giving up, endpoint: didn't launch correctly`

When I deploy it on a sagemaker instance, it works fine.
Do you know if there is something I could do, perhaps some docker setting I could change to make sure that the local deployment also works with the larger model.tar.gz?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using SageMaker SDK Local Mode, you can also run vanilla docker commands yourself to imitate the hosted environment:

Such as:

1. Start "local endpoint"

```
image=$1

docker run -v $(pwd)/test_dir:/opt/ml -p 8080:8080 --rm ${image} serve
```

2. Invoke "local endpoint"

```
payload=$1
content=${2:-text/csv}

curl --data-binary @${payload} -H "Content-Type: ${content}" -v http://localhost:8080/invocations
```

https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/main/advanced_functionality/scikit_bring_your_own/container/local_test

Comment: Thank you! I've been looking for this!